# A ternary string is a sequence of 0s, 1s, and 2s.How many ternary strings of length 15 are there/contain exactly seven 0s,five 1s,three 2s/even weight

Tags: combinatorics

> A ternary string is a sequence of 0s, 1s, and 2s. How many ternary strings of
> length $15$ are there?
>
> How many of those strings contain exactly seven $0$s, five
> 1s, and three $2$s?
>
> How many ternary strings of length $15$ have even weight, i.e.,
> contain an even number of 1s?

(1) there are $3^{15}$ of length $15.$
The second two parts I'm not sure about
I know for a binary string (n choose w) will give you the number of strings
of length n and weight w but I'm not sure how to apply this to ternary strings.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For the balanced strings, it may be worthwhile to experiment, and find how many balanced strings have length $1$, length $2$, and length $3$. You should get $2$, $5$, $14$.

Let $a_n$ be the number of balanced strings of length $n$. We find a recurrence for the $a_n$.

There are two types of balanced string of length $n+1$: (i) the ones that end with $0$ or $3$ and (ii) the ones that end in $1$.

The Type (i) strings are obtained by appending a $0$ or $3$ to a balanced string of length $n$. So there are $2a_n$ of these.

The Type (ii) strings are obtained by appending a $0$ or $3$ to an unbalanced string of length $n$. So there are $3^n-a_n$ of these.
Thus
$$a_{n+1}=2a_n+3^n-a_n=a_n+3^n.$$
Now we can rapidly find $a_{15}$. We can even get a nice general formula for $a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, first you choose seven locations for the $0$'s. How many ways to do that?  For each one, you have eight locations left and need to choose five for the $1$'s.  For the last, if you want the number of strings with exactly $6\ 1$'s, you choose the locations for the ones, then have $2^9$ ways to fill the rest.  Sum over the even numbers.

Comment: would it be (15 choose 7)*(8 choose 5) for the second part.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: would the last part be ( 15 choose 2)*2^13 + (15 choose 4)*2^11 +(15 choose 6)*2^9 + .......... + (15 choose 14)*2.

Comment: Except that you missed the first term, where there are no 1's.

Comment: ah I see now. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> How many of those strings contain exactly seven 0s, five 1s, and three 2s?

The function $ {n \choose k} $ tells you how many subsets of size $ k $ you can choose from a set of size $ n $. So you can choose $ {15 \choose 7} $ configurations for $ 0 $'s - then, from the remaining $ 8 $, you can choose $ {8 \choose 5} $ for the $ 1 $'s. There are three remaining spots, so we're done.

> How many ternary strings of length 15 have even weight, i.e., contain an even number of 1s?

There can be $ 0, 2, 4, \dots, 14 $  ones. So, for each $ k = 1 \dots 7 $ you need to compute how many strings there are containing exactly $ 2k $ ones.